# django.db.utils.OperationalError: foreign key mismatch - "django_admin_log" referencing "transcript_userprofile"

Tags: python, django

when I create superuser, I meet this problem.

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: foreign key mismatch - "django_admin_log" referencing "transcript_userprofile"
```

transcript/models.py:

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    student_num = models.CharField(unique=True, null= False, max_length=9)
    birthday = models.DateField(verbose_name='生日', null=True, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=(('male', '男'),('female', '女')), default='female')
    address = models.CharField(verbose_name='地址', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(verbose_name='城市', max_length=20, default='Windsor')
    province = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='省', default='ON')
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=6, verbose_name='post code',blank=True, null=True )
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    enter_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='入学时间', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'StudentInfo'
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

I deleted all my table except auth_user before, and I encountered this problem. 
Anyone help?

Comment: which tables did you delete?

Answer (score -1):

Probably you forgot to makemagrations and migrate your changes. First do

> **python manage.py makemigrations *yourappname***

then

> **python manage.py migrate**

Also don't forget to register your models in Django-admin.